# Dynamically set ID in UnderscoreJS template generated using Jade

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, pug

I'm using Jade to generate JST templates but I'm having trouble setting placeholder for the id field.

```
.somediv(id=<%= id %>)
    ...
```

Jade compiler throws an error for the above syntax

```
undefined:501
buf.push(attrs({ terse: true, 'id':(<%= id %>), "class": ('somediv')
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct [syntax for attributes](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#attributes) seems to be:

```
.somediv(id=id)
    ...
```

But if you need `id` to be exactly `<%= id %>` then you have to quote it and use `!=` for values that shouldn't be escaped

```
.somediv(id!="<%= id %>")
    ...
```